# Is it possible to have an enhanced version of the singletitle option?

Tags: biblatex

I have the following problem with biblatex: I use a cite style that has a full citation in footnotes for the first citation, subsequent citations refer back to the first footnote (similar to verbose-note/verbose-inote). These subsequent citations should only comprise the author’s last name and the reference to the footnote in which it was cited first, *unless* there is more than one work of this author in this footnote. Thus, I am looking for a functionality similar to the “singletitle” option, only not with regard to all cited works, but only limited to one footnote.

To illustrate the problem, I include a minimal example. “Nachname” should have no shorttitle, since the reference to the respective footnote is already unambiguous. It should look like the one for “Dritter”. But “Buchautor” should have a shorttitle, since there are two works of this author in the footnote with the first citations. By the way, the option “singletitle” is set by verbose-note and verbose-inote, so there is no need to give it here explicitly.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\listfiles
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Nachname1,
  author = {Nachname, Vorname},
  title = {Titel des Zeitschriftenartikels},
 shorttitle = {Titel},
  journal = {Zeitschrift},
  date = {2006},
  volume = {6},
  pages = {19--75}
}
@BOOK{Buchautor1,
  author = {Buchautor, Hans-Wilhelm},
  title = {Irgendein Buch},
 shorttitle = {Irgendein},
  location = {Buch am Wald},
  date = {2000}
}
@BOOK{Nachname2,
  author = {Nachname, Vorname},
  title = {Ein Buch},
 shorttitle = {Buch},
  date = {2004},
 location = {Berlin}
}
@BOOK{Buchautor2,
  author = {Buchautor, Hans-Wilhelm},
  title = {Ein weiteres Buch},
 shorttitle = {Weiteres},
  location = {München},
  date = {2002} 
}
@ARTICLE{Dritter,
 author = {Dritter, Dieter},
 title = {Der Dreisprung in Geschichte und Gegenwart},
 shorttitle = {Dreisprung},
 date = {2010},
 journal = {Dynamik}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}

\usepackage[
  style=verbose-inote
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}
\footcite{Nachname1,Dritter}
\footcite{Nachname2}
\footcite{Buchautor1,Buchautor2}
\footcite{Dritter}
\footcite{Nachname2}
\footcite{Buchautor2}
\footcite{Buchautor1}
\footcite{Nachname1}
\end{document}
```

Has anyone a clue where I could start off?

Comment: If you find a good solution for this, it should also be forwarded to Philipp Lehman for his consideration for a future version of biblatex...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I've got it. :-)

Printing the shorttitle in subseqent citations is controlled by the boolean switch `singletitle` which refers to data in the bbl-file. This switch must be replaced by something more sophisticated.

- I created a new counter `citecommand` which is incremented whenever a command like `\footcite` is used.
- Every time an entry is cited the first time, the macros `footcite:full` and `footcite:save` are called. I added some functionality to `footcite:save` so that it a) saves the current value of `citecommand` and b) creates a unique command derived from the value of `citecommand` and the entry's `fullhash` field (which is a unique hash string for each author). If this command is defined the first time, it will expand to "single", after that to "multi".
- In the macro `footcite:note` which is used for subsequent citations, I replaced the `\ifsingletitle` test by a status test of the respective "first-cite" unique command.

The following must be added to the preamble of the minimal example of domwass:

```
\newcounter{citecommand}% NEW

\renewbibmacro*{prenote}{%
  \stepcounter{citecommand}% NEW
  \iffieldundef{prenote}
    {}
    {\printfield{prenote}%
     \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}

\makeatletter

\renewbibmacro*{footcite:save}{%
  \csxdef{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}{\the\value{instcount}}%
  \label{cbx@\the\value{instcount}}%
  \csxdef{cbx@g@\thefield{entrykey}}{\the\value{citecommand}}% NEW
  \ifcsdef{cbx@\the\value{citecommand}@\thefield{fullhash}}{% NEW
    \csxdef{cbx@\the\value{citecommand}@\thefield{fullhash}}{multi}% NEW
  }{% NEW
    \csxdef{cbx@\the\value{citecommand}@\thefield{fullhash}}{single}% NEW
  }% NEW
}

\renewbibmacro*{footcite:note}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\printfield{label}}
    {\printnames{labelname}}%
%   \ifsingletitle% DELETED
  \ifcsstring{cbx@\csuse{cbx@g@\thefield{entrykey}}@\thefield{fullhash}}{single}% NEW
    {}
    {\setunit*{\nametitledelim}%
     \printfield[title]{labeltitle}}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printtext{%
    \bibstring{seenote}\addnbspace
    \ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}%
    \iftoggle{cbx:pageref}
      {\ifsamepage{\the\value{instcount}}
                  {\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}
         {}
     {\addcomma\space\bibstring{page}\addnbspace
      \pageref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}
      {}}}

\makeatother
```

EDIT: Since no (direct) reference to the value of `citecommand` is needed, `\stepcounter{citecommand}` is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @lockstep (and also @Will for the bounty), this seems to work – although I did not get it to work in my special case with footnote-dw, but this is another issue. At least, you pointed me to a solution.

Comment: Sorry to hear it doesn't solve your exact problem, but bounty awarded regardless `:)`