# Can I count the number of times each reference is cited?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, counters

I am writing a paper, and I would like to be able to find out automatically how many times each reference is cited. This could either be appended to the references in a printed version, or outputted as a separate file.

I've seen [Check if an entry is cited multiple times](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12679/check-if-an-entry-is-cited-multiple-times), but it focusses on checking each reference at the point of citation, while I want to do an overall count.

The reasons are twofold. Firstly, to see if any references are being 'overcited'. Secondly, if space becomes an issue, to be able to see easily which references are only being cited once and could potentially be removed with minimum fuss.

Comment: Only 2 answers!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you're willing to switch to [`biblatex`](http://ftp.univie.ac.at/packages/tex/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex.html), you may use the `citecounter` feature that was added in v1.3.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[citecounter=true]{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{%
  \addperiod\space
  (Cited \arabic{citecounter}~time\ifnumequal{\value{citecounter}}{1}{}{s})%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{A01}.

Some text \autocite{B02}.

Some text \autocite{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Stangely, when I switch from `style=authoryear` to `style=apa`,  most of the citation counts disappear. Any ideas on why this is happening? Perhaps I need to provide a minimal example.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `backref` or `pagebackref` options to `hyperref` to get links to section or page numbers after each reference in the bibliography if you don't want to switch to biblatex.

Comment: IIRC, the `backref` option doesn't tell you if a reference was cited multiple times on the same page.

Comment: @lockstep: Yes, you're absolutely right. I should have pointed out that this just gives a rough indication of how often a reference is cited. (Also, I could have sworn I upvoted your answer...fixed.)

Comment: @lockstep: with version 1.21 or later of `backref` there is the `\backrefalt` formatting hook that gives access to the number of duplicate citations. Since version 1.33 the `\backrefentrycount` wrapper makes this more easily accessible.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for my natbib-powered document (it's the code OP used on [How to show Not cited and Cited i times on pages ..., in the bibliography when using biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/390536/12065)). Just paste this somewhere in the preamble and you can easily see in the references which entries are the most and least cited.

```
\usepackage[pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4] {
    \ifcase #1
        No citation in the text.
    \or
        Cited on page #2.
    \else
        Cited #1 times on pages #2.
    \fi
}
```

P.S.: I remember using a simpler solution a couple of years ago, IIRC there is a package that automatically does something similar to the code above.