# Citation lists with different styles

Tags: biblatex

I want create a list my publications, after each publication there is a note that includes the number of times the article has been cited followed by the list of citations in chronologic order. A small example is below:

---

[1] Nalesnik MA, Woodle ES, Dimaio JM, Vasudev B, Teperman LW, Covington S, Taranto S, Gockerman JP, Shapiro R, Sharma V, Swinnen LJ, Yoshida A, Ison MG. Donor Transmitted Malignancies in Organ Transplantation: Assessment Of Clinical Risk. Am J Transplant 2011 Jun;11(6):1140-1147. DOI: 10.1097/TP.0b013e3182762dd0, PMID: 23149478

This article has been cited 2 times including several national organ transplant guidelines and WHO projects.

Citations:

1. Chapman, J. R. & Nalesnik, M. A. (2012),
   Despite the best intentions cancer is transmissible by transplantation.
   Transplantation 94(12), 1185--1186.
   DOI: 10.1097/TP.0b013e3182762dd0, PMID: 23149478
2. Kim, B.; Woreta, T.; Chen, P.-H.; Limketkai, B.; Singer, A.; Dagher, N.; Cameron, A.; Lin, M.-T.; Kamel, I. & Gurakar, A. (2013)
   Donor-Transmitted Malignancy in a Liver Transplant Recipient: A Case Report and Review of Literature
   Dig Dis Sci 58(5), 1185—1190,
   DOI: 10.1007/s10620-012-2501-0, PMID: 23242807

   ---

The counter for the cited articles should be updated when I update the bib file.

At present I am formatting the publications individually and creating sub documents with only the citations (generated by biblatex) and adding them after each publication manually.

I was able to create a list of my publications with a counter using biblatex but to add sub bibliographic lists of citations for each is beyond my luddite capabilities.

I know reading from this list Strongbad had done something for curriculum vitae that could be adapted for this but no code was available.

Any help would be appreciated or directions what to read.

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you're asking for. Can you provide a MWE? Maybe this question can help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14158/can-i-count-the-number-of-times-each-reference-is-cited?rq=1