# Table with bibtex

Tags: tables, bibtex

I am looking to compile a bibliography as a table with three columns:

1. ref number, based on chronology of article
2. full citation
3. number of citations

I am using a .bib file in overleaf.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Leslie

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14158/134144 could be interesting.

Comment: OMG - this looks perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I played around with this and it's not quite what I'm looking for. Rather, I'd like to compile the number of external citations from, e.g., Google Scholar or similar. Any ideas?