# select shorthands in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I have a large `.bib` database in which lots of entries have `shorthands` fields defined.

When I want to limit the usage of those shorthands only to the most cited texts, I generaly create a copy of the bibliography database to the working directory and either delete the unwanted shorthands or change the field to something like `XXXshorthand`, in order to hide it from bibtex/biber.

Now I'd like to automate that process. I imagine two ways of accomplishing that:

1. Somenthing like `\includeonly` command, that I can set at the
   preamble, adding the entries that are allowed to have shorthands (I
   don't know if it is possible or how to do it, but it would check if
   the bib entry is equal to the ones listed and if not add a
   `\clearfield{shorthand}` to them).
2. A very different approach, but one that might be more general than that, is to check if a given entry is cited more than three or five times (something definable by the user) and if so allowing it to use its shorthands.

So the question is if it is possible and if so, how?

**EDIT**

Folowing @ienissei's comment, which pointed to [an answer by @lockstep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18087/5872), I've able, so far to both ignore `shorthandintro` (which prints the string `citedas` —in english, "henceforth cited as..."— and the shorthand in the first citation) and to make subsequent citations (up to three) to ignore the shorthand and use the `cite:short` bibmacro.

Here's a MWE of what I did so far, drawn on the top of the one provided by the mentioned answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad3,citecounter=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
  \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
      @misc{A01,
        author = {Author, A.},
        year = {2001},
        title = {Alpha},
        shorthand = {AL},
      }
      @misc{B02,
        author = {Buthor, B.},
        year = {2002},
        title = {Bravo},
        shorthand = {BR},
      }
  \end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% Command to tell how much citations activate the use of shorthands
  \newcommand{\shthreshold}[1]{\newcommand{\SHthreshold}{#1}}
  \shthreshold{3}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \ifciteseen
    {\ifciteibid
       {\ifloccit
    {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:opcit}}
        {\ifnumgreater{\value{citecounter}}{\SHthreshold}%
        {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:short}}}}}
       {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:short}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{citecounter}}{\SHthreshold}{
    \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}{}}

\begin{document}
\printshorthands
Some text \autocite{B02}. Some text \autocite{B02}. Some text \autocite{B02}. 
Some text \autocite{A01}. Some text \autocite{A01}. Some text \autocite{A01}. 
Some text \autocite{B02}. Some text \autocite{B02}. Some text \autocite{B02}. 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It works perfectly well, except that it still prints the entry in the list of shorthands.

**EDIT2**: I change the code, because it wasn't working with entries witout shorthands. The problem was with the `\iffieldundef{shorthand}`.

Comment: There is a `citecounter` option that can be enabled in `biblatex`, which will create the appropriate counter and macro. Maybe [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18087/10119) could help you.

Comment: @ienissei It really helps! I've been able to both stop `shorthandintro` bibmacro (as done in that answer) and skip to a `cite:short` the few other citations. However, I have no idea how to remove the entry from the list of shorthands...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a suitable bibliography category and use it in `\printshorthands`. This is very similar to my answer to [How to split bibliography into "works cited" and "works not cited"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/how-to-split-bibliography-into-works-cited-and-works-not-cited).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad3,citecounter=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  shorthand = {AL},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
  shorthand = {BR},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% Command to tell how much citations activate the use of shorthands
\newcommand{\shthreshold}[1]{\newcommand{\SHthreshold}{#1}}
\shthreshold{3}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \ifciteseen
    {\ifciteibid
       {\ifloccit
    {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:opcit}}
        {\ifnumgreater{\value{citecounter}}{\SHthreshold}%
        {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:short}}}}}
       {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:short}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{citecounter}}{\SHthreshold}{
    \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}{}}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{allowshorthand}
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{citecounter}}{\SHthreshold}{%
    \addtocategory{allowshorthand}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
  }{%
  }%
}

\textheight=250pt% just for the example

\begin{document}

\printshorthands[category=allowshorthand]

Some text \autocite{B02}. Some text \autocite{B02}. Some text \autocite{B02}. 
Some text \autocite{A01}. Some text \autocite{A01}. Some text \autocite{A01}. 
Some text \autocite{B02}. Some text \autocite{B02}. Some text \autocite{B02}. 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer, hadn't thought of that. I will delete mine.