# Use Abbrivation when citing with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I am learning to use `biblatex` for my thesis. I have a question regarding the citation. I would like to cite a dictionary (book) as an abbreviation in the text and show it in the bibliography as

Abbrivation = Authors (Year): Title. Place: Publisher.

I would like to know if that is even possible.

For example in text

> As we see in DAWB (2010: p. 5) ...

In the bibliography

> DAWB = Krech, Eva-Maria/Stock, Eberhard/Hirschfeld, Ursula/Anders, Lutz Christian (2010): *Deutsches Aussprachewörterbuch*. Berlin/New York: de Gruyter.

Comment: Have you seen how you can add "shorthand" to entries in the bib file and what that does? It doesn't do exactly what you want, but it's similar (and the explanation will be under a separate heading first in the bibliography). Even though it is not exactly what you want I think it will benefit you if you look that up, try to use it and edit your question to show an example using it, asking how to change something in what you get in that example.

Comment: Tip: When making an example for a question about biblatex a possibility many don't know about is to use the `biblatex-examples.bib` that comes with biblatex, so you don't have to add any bib file to your question. See how I used that when asking a biblatex question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325159/henceforth-cited-as-when-there-are-no-more-citations-in-biblatex . That question was actually about the "shorthand" feature, so it also mentions some entries in `biblatex-examples.bib` that make use of that.